# How to load the data from Parse synchronously?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, pfquery

Anyone who is professional at PFQuery? I got a problem.

The query does not follow the code order that I wrote, like in my Xcode file, the order is query1, query2, query3 and then query4. However, when the code was executing, the contents of the query stuffs appear without following the 1,2,3,4 order. And that really bring a trouble to me. Please help. Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

 SAC_rateSum=0;
 SAC_rateNumbers=0;

NSMutableArray *SAC_CG_rateNumber = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery * SAC_CG_rateAQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SAC_CG_Rate"];

[SAC_CG_rateAQuery selectKeys:@[@"rate"]];
[SAC_CG_rateAQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        [SAC_CG_rateNumber addObject:[object objectForKey:@"rate"]];
    }

    for (NSNumber *n in SAC_CG_rateNumber) {

        SAC_rateSum +=[n doubleValue];

    }

    SAC_rateNumbers+=SAC_CG_rateNumber.count;
    NSLog(@"CG:%.0f",SAC_rateNumbers);

    }];

NSMutableArray *SAC_MP_rateNumber = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery * SAC_MP_rateAQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SAC_MP_Rate"];

[SAC_MP_rateAQuery selectKeys:@[@"rate"]];
[SAC_MP_rateAQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        [SAC_MP_rateNumber addObject:[object objectForKey:@"rate"]];

    }
    for (NSNumber *n in SAC_MP_rateNumber) {

        SAC_rateSum +=[n doubleValue];
    }

   SAC_rateNumbers+=SAC_MP_rateNumber.count;
    NSLog(@"MP:%.0f",SAC_rateNumbers);
}];





NSMutableArray *SAC_NS_rateNumber = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery * SAC_NS_rateAQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SAC_NS_Rate"];

[SAC_NS_rateAQuery selectKeys:@[@"rate"]];
[SAC_NS_rateAQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        [SAC_NS_rateNumber addObject:[object objectForKey:@"rate"]];

        }

    for (NSNumber *n in SAC_NS_rateNumber) {

        SAC_rateSum +=[n doubleValue];
    }

   SAC_rateNumbers += SAC_NS_rateNumber.count;

    NSLog(@"NS:%.0f",SAC_rateNumbers);


}];
NSMutableArray *SAC_SB_rateNumber = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery * SAC_SB_rateAQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SAC_SB_Rate"];

[SAC_SB_rateAQuery selectKeys:@[@"rate"]];
[SAC_SB_rateAQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        [SAC_SB_rateNumber addObject:[object objectForKey:@"rate"]];

    }
    for (NSNumber *n in SAC_SB_rateNumber) {

        SAC_rateSum +=[n doubleValue];
    }

    SAC_rateNumbers+=SAC_SB_rateNumber.count;
    NSLog(@"SB:%.0f",SAC_rateNumbers);
}];


NSMutableArray *SAC_WiU_rateNumber = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery * SAC_WiU_rateAQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SAC_WiU_Rate"];

[SAC_WiU_rateAQuery selectKeys:@[@"rate"]];
[SAC_WiU_rateAQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        [SAC_WiU_rateNumber addObject:[object objectForKey:@"rate"]];
    }

    for (NSNumber *n in SAC_WiU_rateNumber) {

        SAC_rateSum+=[n doubleValue];
    }

   SAC_rateNumbers+=SAC_WiU_rateNumber.count;
    NSLog(@"WIU:%.0f",SAC_rateNumbers);
}];


        NSMutableArray *SAC_WS_rateNumber = [NSMutableArray array];

PFQuery * SAC_WS_rateAQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SAC_WS_Rate"];

[SAC_WS_rateAQuery selectKeys:@[@"rate"]];
[SAC_WS_rateAQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        [SAC_WS_rateNumber addObject:[object objectForKey:@"rate"]];
              }

    for (NSNumber *n in SAC_WS_rateNumber) {

       SAC_rateSum +=[n doubleValue];
    }


    SAC_rateNumbers+=SAC_WS_rateNumber.count;
    NSLog(@"WS:%.0f",SAC_rateNumbers);
    self.dininghallAscoreLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"         %.1f", SAC_rateSum/SAC_rateNumbers];
    self.dininghallAratesLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f rates",SAC_rateNumbers];
    NSLog(@"%.1f",SAC_rateSum);
    NSLog(@"TOTAL: %.0f",SAC_rateNumbers);

}];





   }
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: When do you plan to post your c# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is best to answer your question with an example:

If I prepare 4 dishes of food: eggs, steak, stir-fry and rice

I then place them on the stove one after another, why don't they all finish cooking in that order?

Of course it is easy to see from the example that each dish takes a while to cook, and different things don't finish at the same time.... the same is true with **async** code!

When you call `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` it is like saying "put this on to cook, and when it is done do this with the results (the block part)".

The code in the block runs later, when your query finishes. The order is not going to be the same each time, and one or more of them could actually fail due to network issues.